# Importing class variable python

Tags: python, python-import

I have two python classes, one uses the other's variable

class A:

```
class A(object):

    variable = None

    @classmethod
    def init_variable(cls):
        cls.variable = something
```

class B:

```
variable = __import__('module').A.variable

class B(object):

    @staticmethod
    def method():
        return variable
```

I simplified my problem as much as possible. So my question is why I still have `B.method()` returning `NoneType` even if I update `A.variable` class variable with `something` using `init_variable`

Comment: Those are two separate variables. You may want to read about [how Python variables work](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: I think when you import module `A` like this you create a new instance of that module instead of importing the already existing module. Also, when do you update `A.variable`?

Comment: @Peter that's what I'm suspecting. In fact I'm making a package and `A.variable` need user input so I want `B` class to work with this variable when it's updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a bit so that it'd actually do what you want:

your_package/klass_A.py

```
class A(object):
    variable = None

    @classmethod
    def init_variable(cls, something):
        cls.variable = something
```

your_package/klass_B.py

```
from your_package.klass_A import A

class B(object):
    @staticmethod
    def method():
        return A.variable
```

Now, you can actually update `A.variable` and use the updated variable in `B` as well. For example this:

```
print B.method()
A.init_variable('123')
print B.method()
```

returns:

```
None
123
```